# JSpinner with a SpinnerNumberModel gets stuck when an initial value with four decimal digits is used

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

If I run the following Java spinner example with a starting value of

```
double v = 3.146;
```

the up/down arrows on the spinner work as expected.  However, if I use a starting value of

```
double v = 3.1466;
```

the arrow buttons no longer seem to work.

As I understand this is related to rounding up of the displayed value to three decimal digits, which in the latter case results in a value of 3.147 and is of course outside the range of the spinner.  However, my original value was obviously not outside the specified max value.

Is there a way to make sure that as long as my initial value is within [min,max] range, the spinner buttons work as expected?

```
public class spinner_test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Frame");

        double v = 3.1466; // Makes the spinner buttons non functional
        // double v = 3.146; // Work OK
        SpinnerNumberModel m = new SpinnerNumberModel(v, 0, v, 0.005);
        JSpinner s = new JSpinner(m);

        f.add(s);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.pack();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Set a custom editor for the spinner to display the 4 decimals:

```
JSpinner.NumberEditor numberEditor = new JSpinner.NumberEditor(s,"0.0000");
s.setEditor(numberEditor);
```

Comment: I don't necessarily want to show four decimals. Even then, the same problem would still exist, but now between the original data with five decimals and the displayed value with four decimals.

Comment: `with five decimals` - what do you mean 5 decimals? Your question is about 4 decimals. Using your code the down arrow works right away and the up arrow will work after you have used the down arrow.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear about my explanation.  Basically, I meant that as long as there is a discrepancy in the number of decimal digits (e.g. 5 digits) specified in the original value and the number of decimal digits (e.g. 4 digits) shown in the spinner, there is a chance that the spinner arrow buttons will stop working due to rounding.  I was looking for a solution that would not necessitate knowing how many digits were used in the original value.

Comment: I would guess you would need to look at the SpinnerNumberModel. It implements `getPrevious()` and `getNext()` methods. So I guess it would be responsible for any rounding that might occur.